# local .svn directory disappears after crash

Tags: eclipse, macos, maven, svn, eclipse-kepler

Once in a while my mac gets stuck and then I need to hard reset it using the power button. A short time (but not immediately) after reboot, the `.svn` directories in my eclipse project directories disappear.

The call to `svn info` returns:

> svn: E155007: '../workspaces/project_name' is not a working copy

It means I can't work with svn and need to checkout all the stuff all over again. This happened to me few times now and I really don't know why.
Things I've tried and did not solve the problem:

- Replacing Eclipse
- Upgrading svn version
- Upgrading Maven version

relevant version data:

- Apache Maven 3.1.1
- Java version: 1.7.0_51
- mac os X 10.9.1
- Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1
- svn, version 1.8.5 (r1542147)

I'm quite clueless about this issue and would like to hear any ideas...

Comment: In svn 1.7 the `.svn` directories were moved to the source root. So you would not see `.svn` in the child of the root. But as you are using svn 1.8 it should work.

Comment: It happened to me again - this time without the computer crashing. Again all .svn folders disappeared, just while working regularly in Eclipse. Any ideas before completely re-installing my Mac?